# Limit CONCAT to 32.767 chars [IMPALA]

Tags: sql, impala

Basically, I have a table that looks something like this:

```
| id | string_col |
| -- | ---------- |
| 1  | aaaaaaa    |
| 1  | bbbbbbb    |
| 1  | ccccccc    |
| 2  | aaaaaaa    |
| 2  | bbbbbbb    |
| 2  | ccccccc    |
```

and a query that groups the rows by ids and concatenates the string_col values for that id:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(string_col)), ']') AS strings_list
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

the result looks like this:

```
| id | strings_list                |
| -- | --------------------------- |
| 1  | [aaaaaaa, bbbbbbb, ccccccc] |
| 2  | [aaaaaaa, bbbbbbb, ccccccc] |
```

The query does what I want, but I need to export the results in excel. The cell max length in excel is 32.767 characters and in some cases the length for `strings_list` is way above that and messes up the entire file.

Is there any way I could limit the `CONCAT` to 32.767 chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the LEFT function e.g.

```
LEFT(CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(string_col)), ']'))
```

Comment: you mean `LEFT(CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(string_col)), ']'),32766)` ?